# Mongoose fetch data from collection A if it's reference exists on collection B

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I need your help please with a mongoose query for my express app.

I have 3 collections Movies, TvShows and Trailers and I need to fetch all movies or shows that have trailers.
here are the models:

```js
var TrailerSchema = new Schema(
  {
    link: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    movieId: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Movie' },
    showId: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Show' },
  }
)
module.exports = mongoose.model('Trailer', trailerSchema)
```

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const Schema = mongoose.Schema

var movieSchema = new Schema(
  {
    title: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    rating: {
      type: Number,
    },
  }
)
module.exports = mongoose.model('Movie', movieSchema)
```

in the Trailer collection there are some documents with the movieId field and some with showId.
Now how can I fetch all the movies or shows that have trailers?

Answer (score 0):

because you just stored `movieId` in `TrailerSchema` and  `movieSchema` don't have field like `TrailerId:[{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Trailer'}]`, can not use populate...
but for your issue at first

```
let listOfIds = await Link.find( { movieId: { $exists: true } }, 'movieId._id' ).lean()
```

I don't know real data stored in Trailer collection for query in `Trailer.find` after get IDs you should search in Movie collection to get all info

```
 let listOfMovies = await Movie.find({ _id: { $in: listOfIds.map((id) => {if(id.movieId) return id.movieId._id}  ) }, })
```

Comment: Thanks for the help Mohammed, I tweaked your solution a bit and now I get the listOfIds but the listOfMovies is an empty array.
here are the tweaks:
let listOfIds = await Link.find( { movieId: { $exists: true } }, '_id' ).exec()
let listOfMovies = await Movie.find({ _id: { $in: listOfIds.map((id) => id._id) }, })

Comment: you can edit my answer, because you added a little information about question, just I want to show you the manner for fetch data

Comment: Thanks for showing me, would you please help me with the listOfMovies query I get an empty array and there is no error, I've been searching for a solution but I still don't have a clue.

Comment: can you get  listOfIds ? or is an empty array\

Comment: I do get a listOfIds yes

Comment: can you check my answer again, and tell me the result?

Comment: Here is the console.log 
list of Movies []

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property '_id' of undefined

Comment: Still nothing no errors just an empty array :(

Comment: you first query is incorrect perhaps, `{ $exists: true }`, added real stored data to the question

Comment: here is the console.log of listOfIds

list of ids [
  { _id: 600a1d376d1a08a606684822 },
  { _id: 600ac1b8c05a373658453eb0 }
]

Comment: it is imposible, why do you use Link model??? you should search on Trailer Model??what is Link Mode?

Comment: I renamed Trailer model to Link because I added a a new field for the cover of the movie, it is not a big deal since the first query works fine

Comment: it's important, because in query you select  `movieId._id`, but in the result, you can see list of array without  `movieId` key, your first query is similar with my answer?

Comment: See what I've done: let listOfIds = await Link.find(
      { movieId: { $exists: true } },
      '_id'
    ).exec()
    let x = listOfIds.map((id) => id._id)
    console.log('list of ids', x)
    let listOfMovies = await Movie.find({
      _id: {
        $in: x,
      },
    })
    console.log('list of Movies', listOfMovies)

and here is the reslut:

list of ids [ 600a1d376d1a08a606684822, 600ac1b8c05a373658453eb0 ]
list of Movies []

Comment: please run my query in my answer, your query is different with my answer

Comment: Still the same, this is so strange

Comment: No, you select _id, but i want select moveiId._id in first query

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227711/discussion-between-getsuga-and-mohammad-yaser-ahmadi).